# How do I get SteamID through LuaFFI?

Tags: lua, ffi, steam

How do I get SteamID through LuaFFI?

Hi, I need to get SteamID through **LuaFFI** in csgo (the script will be loaded through Pandora.gg). So from available libraries **only** bit and ffi

I tried to use the code I found on the internet(tried to find it now but couldn't find it:P), but it didn't start and just crashed...